# C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath_target_10073078\java.exe

Tags: java

Alguien me podría ayudar a entender por qué la instalación de java me crea un `javapath_target`  como el siguiente.

Quiero entender  cual es la función y que sucede si borro la ruta

```
"C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath_target_10073078\java.exe"
```

Gracias.

Comment: es un symlink, no pasa nada si borras a ruta, pero es muy conveniente tenerlo si tienes varias versiones de JDK instaladas

Comment: Gracias Ruslan. Tengo varias instalaciones de  bundles que me instalan su propia version de Java. Alguna recomendacion que m pudieras dar para no dañar las instalaciones de los bundles si remuevo la ruta mencionada arriba?

Comment: configura tu javahome, algunas aplicaciones de oracle como el jdeveloper funcionan de maravilla si le borras su jre embebido y usas en su lugar el jre/jdk asi tal cual simplemente configurandolos en tu javahome y agregando el susodicho a tu variable path